# Why is size of paid/0$ apps "unknown" in USC?

Tags: software-center

When you look at the **free software** in Ubuntu software center,you will be shown the Size of those apps as below.

> **Total size** 32mb to download,100mb when installed.

But in case of **paid softwares(not installed)** you are shown.

> **Total size** Unknown

Basically,all that USC has to do is that send a call to the server to know the size of the **.deb** package(that's what it does when it says **Total size**  **calculating...**)
Then why can't USC do the same with paid apps?

**NOTE:-** If we know the size of software we are about to download,it helps a lot when your network connection is slow.You can ensure that you won't fall less by few Mb's while downloading an app of Gb's.And you can avoid the embarrassment that comes due to it.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in Ubuntu software-center (Bug #911215 ).
But a fix was released and in Ubuntu 13.10 I can see the sizes of paid applications too. 
For more information on this bug see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/911215